# R: regression with rational functions

Tags: r, regression

I am new to `R` and have to perform a polynomial regression with rational functions in `R`. The function is as follows:

```
numerator is A0 + A1*y + A2*y^2 
denominator is B0 + B1*y + B2*y^2
```

and the rational function is

```
F= -(numerator)/denominator
```

So we are given values of `F` and values of `y` with the constants A0, A1, A2, B0, B1 and B2 to be determined.

How to perform such a regression in `R`?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any error term in this? Or are the values of F the exact values of the polynomial ratio evaluated at y? Regression normally involves error terms: y = Ax + N(0,sigma) or similar. Its the important bit. If there's no error then it's not really regression, its "solve for A0,A1,A2..." etc.

Comment: In general, `nls` will fit any function you want.  Is there a reason (e.g. homework) that you must fit your data to this function form?  It's often faster and easier (and with comparable residual fitting errors) to fit data to a simple polynomial regardless of the original generating function.

Comment: @ Spacedman I am assuming a fit of this form to my data. Of course there will be error terms. Where can I find more information on how to properly formulate a regression problem? 1 vote up.

Comment: @ Carl I found a similar example on the web that uses such a rational function up to degree 2 to fit the kind of data that I have. Taking away one or more terms will not give a proper fit. 1 vote up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `rationalfit` in package `pracma` will do this, but you have to take some care when handling poles. See the following example:

```
f <- function(x) -(x^2-3*x+2)/(x^2+1)
xs <- seq(0, 3, len=21); ys <- f(xs)

library(pracma)
rationalfit(xs, ys, d1=2, d2=2)
# $p1 = -1  3  -2
# $p2 = 1.000000e+00 -3.663736e-15  1.000000e+00
```

`d1` and `d2` are the maximally allowed degrees of the numerator and denominator polynomials.

If data are inexact, it will fit the polynomial coefficients in a least-squares sense. There are no error terms or statistical measures (like in `lm`), it is a simple computation from numerical analysis.

Comment: @ Hans Thanks for your answer. Yes poles should be avoided as far as possible in the desired fit range. 1 vote up.

Comment: I found this useful for my work.  It isn't the OP's question, but thanks for providing utility to me in what I am doing.